# How to link two excel file and link column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two excel file with product data. Both the excel file have one unique column data. Now what I want that when I change value of description column in master table then I want to update same column in transaction table on same barcode number.

Master list.xlsx
[image]

Consolidated list.xlsx
[image]

Below formula I have created and and I am getting error #N/A

```
=VLOOKUP($F3,'[Master List.xlsx]MasterList'!$F$3:$A$650,3,0)
```

Comment: tr using ```INDEX(MATCH(...))```

Answer (score 0):

### Using INDEX/MATCH

In cell `A3` use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('[Master List.xlsx]MasterList'!A$3:A$650,MATCH($F3,'[Master List.xlsx]MasterList'!$B$3:$B$650,0)),"")
```

Adjust the `A$3:A$650` to 'retrieve' values from other columns, e.g. if you need the values from the column of the first `0.854` next to the unique (ID) column, use `C$3:C$650` instead.